# Deleting audit log data pertaining to specific entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to delete audit log data pertaining to specific entity only? We have a huge audit log which we wanted to reduce by purging log data of specific entities though we do want to keep other entities logs.

Comment: Do you have any need at all for the log data you will purge for specific entities? If not, just turn off logging on those entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no support method for deleting Audit Log entries by entity type. The only method support for audit deletion is by date (i.e., all records older than X date.) *Note: that depending on the SQL environment the available end dates may be limited to the end date of an audit log partition. *

That said, there is an unsupported method for meeting this requirement. **CRITICAL: Take your CRM server offline, backup the database, and test a restore before attempting - there is no support available for what I'm going to suggest, since this goes against the supported actions on Dynamics CRM 2011 SQL database.**

The audit logs are stored in a table `dbo.AuditBase`. This table does not have an extension base, so there is only one record per audit entry to worry about.

You will need the `ObjectTypeCode` of the entity. You can get this from the database by running the following script:

`SELECT [EntityId],[Name],[ObjectTypeCode] 

FROM [].[MetadataSchema].[Entity] ORDER BY Name`

Now that you have the `ObjectTypeCode` simply replace the xxxx in the script below with the value and run the script.

`DELETE FROM [].[dbo].[AuditBase] WHERE ObjectTypeCode = xxxx`

Audit records for specific entity type are now gone!

Answer (score 1):

I know it isn't quite what you are looking for, but there is a [DeleteAuditDataRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.deleteauditdatarequest.aspx) API message that you can call to delete all audit data before a specific date.

As far as deleting specific records I don't believe you can.  If you try out the following code you will get the following error *The 'Delete' method does not support entities of type 'audt'*

```
orgService.Delete("audit",auditId);
```

If it is an on premise environment you have direct DB access and you can archive the audit records or delete them via SQL.

Hope that helps.

Comment: orgService.Delete() gives and error as delete operation is not available for audit entity.